# Python append item to array reading in xml file

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python and learning to read in xml files. 
Running my code to append the items gives me repeated arrays. I guess it is looping through all the items appending and returning an array each time. I just want one array the array of all the items. What am I doing wrong?

The code is as follows:

```
countries_im = []
for country in root.findall('./country'):
        data = {
            'name': None,
            'infant_mortality': None
        }
        data['name'] = country.find('./name').text
        data['infant_mortality'] = country.findtext('./infant_mortality')
        if data['infant_mortality'] is not None:
            countries_im.append(data['infant_mortality'])
            print(countries_im)
```

The result is as follows:

```
['13.19']
['13.19', '4.78']
['13.19', '4.78', '7.9']
['13.19', '4.78', '7.9', '6.16']
['13.19', '4.78', '7.9', '6.16', '3.69']
['13.19', '4.78', '7.9', '6.16', '3.69', '3.31']
```

I just want the last array. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are printing the array at each step of the for-loop. Move the print statement outside the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not returning multiple lists. In fact, it is not returning anything. You have only one existing list that is changing it's content via append.

The result you are showing is the output of calling `print(countries_im)` each time you append an item to the list.

If you change your code to this:

```
countries_im = []
for country in root.findall('./country'):
        data = {
            'name': None,
            'infant_mortality': None
        }
        data['name'] = country.find('./name').text
        data['infant_mortality'] = country.findtext('./infant_mortality')
        if data['infant_mortality'] is not None:
            countries_im.append(data['infant_mortality'])
print(countries_im)
```

You will se that the list that you have in memory have all the items appended.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, your code is correct, you just need to move the `print` statement outside of the `for` loop. In other words, you are printing the same array each time you add something. So, you are ending up with what you want at the end of the `for` loop (the completed array).

Comment: You are correct. How do I move the print statement outside the loop so that I could print only the last final array?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, please see the answer from @david-de-la-iglesia it is correct.